# Precise Timer in Javascript for Metro-Style Apps

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a metro-style app with HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript in which I need a precise timer. setInterval() doesn't fit here because it's not precise enough.

I've tried with Windows.System.Threading, but it doesn't seem to be implemented in javascript (and I don't think it will be). I've also tried with something like:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var init = date.getTime();
    while(init + someTime < date.getTime())
       doNothing();
    doSomething();
```

But obviously, that hasn't worked.

Anyone know how I could do it?

Thanks.

Comment: you seem to be waiting for a specific moment (`init + someTime`).. how about `setTimeout(code, delay)` ? For what purpose could it not be precise enough? Maybe you need a different approach then..

Comment: No, I really meant setInterval(). It's true that my code was more like setTimeout() but it was the kind of stuff I was trying. It's not precise enough for an actual timer that has to be "timering"  in background

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do, or more specifically, why `setInterval` is not precise enough

Comment: I'm trying to do a timer. Just like a pomodoro timer, setting an interval of one second to refresh the timer. When you run the app in the background, the timer doesn't measure the time that has really passed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm following your question but it seems rather than getting more precision you actually just want to make sure the timer fires at the right time, your app in the foreground or otherwise.

In Windows 8 Metro apps unless your app will stop executing code when it goes to the background, so your timer will be missed. Instead you should use background tasks to trigger timed events.

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskbuilder.aspx

Sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any calls available directly in Javascript for you do this. But you can write a WinRT wrapper around the Win32 calls QueryPerformanceCounter and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx) either using C# or C++. These two calls will help you me create a [high precision timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0).